# Unable to save multiple images in database Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table named `"cases`" where the `column` are `id` `image1`,`content1`,`image2`,`content2`,`image`3 and `content3`

My `content1,content2,content3` will be saved in database when i submit it from form but images are nither saved in folder nor in database. I need help

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request,SidContainRequest $request)
    {
        $sidContain = new sidcontain;

        $sidContain->content1 = $request->get('page_content1');
        $sidContain->content2 = $request->get('page_content2');
        $sidContain->content3 = $request->get('page_content3');

        //upload multiple files 
        $files= [];

        if($request->file('leftimage'))   $files[] = $request->file('leftimage');
        if($request->file('Middleimage')) $files[] = $request->fiel('Middleimage');
        if($request->file('Rightimage'))  $files[] = $request->file('Rightimage');

          foreach($files as $flle)
          {
             if(!empty($file))
             {
                $filename[] = $file->getClientOrginalName();
                if(isset($filename)){
                $file->move(base_path().'/frontend/sidimage/',end($filename));
           }
       }
        $sidContain->image1 = $filename[0];
        $sidContain->image2 = $filename[1];
        $sidContain->image3 = $filename[2];





        }

        $ok = $sidContain->save();
        if($ok)
        {
            \Session::flash('flash_message','Report Added Successfully!');
            return Redirect::to('administrator/sidConatin/create');
        }
    }
```

view/form

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Left Image</label>
                        <input type="file" name="leftimage">    
                        @if($errors->has('leftimage')) <p style="color:red;">{{$errors->first('leftimage')}}</p>@endif                
                    </div>



                       <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Left Content</label>
                        <textarea  name="page_content1" id="page_content1" class="editor form-control"></textarea>    
                        @if($errors->has('page_content1'))<p style="color:red;">{{$errors->first('page_content1')}}</p>@endif                     
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Middle Image</label>
                        <input type="file" name="Middleimage">   
                           @if($errors->has('Middleimage')) <p style="color:red;">{{$errors->first('Middleimage')}}</p>@endif                   
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Middle Content</label>
                        <textarea  name="page_content2" id="page_content2" class="editor form-control"></textarea>     
                          @if($errors->has('page_content2')) <p style="color:red;">{{$errors->first('page_content2')}}</p>@endif                       
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Right Image</label>
                        <input type="file" name="Rightimage">    
                          @if($errors->has('Rightimage')) <p style="color:red;">{{$errors->first('Rightimage')}}</p>@endif                     
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Right Content</label>
                       <textarea  name="page_content3" id="page_content3" class="editor form-control"></textarea>     
                         @if($errors->has('page_content3')) <p style="color:red;">{{$errors->first('page_content3')}}</p>@endif                       
                    </div>




                <div style="margin-top: 15px;">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
                </div>

        </form>
```

Comment: You have a typo :  "foreach($files as $flle)" should be  "foreach($files as $file)"

Comment: set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to diplay errors

Comment: @Amarnasan what you are saying i could not understand,please make me abit clear,details...

Comment: @RanjeetKarki You have spelt the word `file` wrong in your foreach declaration. it should be F**I**LE not F**L**LE.

Comment: Also, you should remove the `/` from the end of your destination path. `base_path().'/frontend/sidimage'`

Comment: @Jeemusu thankyou very much